# HighSlide Javascript Thumbnail Viewer

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, highslide

I wanted to add a cool new feature to my website that allows for clickable popup java-script thumbnails using HighSlide. I have thoroughly searched stackoverflow, google, and the forum on highslide for a solution to my problem to no avail.

The main problem I am experience is the onclick java function, which, when clicked, is supposed to enlarge one of the images. However, instead of it opening up, I get a perpetual loading message.

http://untetheredthoughts.com/highslide-custom-example.htm

Upon my examination of other people who have had a similar error, they needed to ensure that all paths to the files were setup correctly, which I have double checked. I am still new to coding, so if anyone could give me some pointers, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you for your time, I am very excited to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a longstanding bug in the "editor" on the Highslide JS site, and it always makes the same mistake! Open the highslide.config.js file, then:

```
Change:

hs.outlineType = 'custom';

To:

hs.outlineType = '';
```

I think that will cure the problem. If not, post back, and we can start looking at some of the other usual suspects. ;)

Comment: I see that my suggested correction fixed the problem. Please mark the answer "correct," matters1776.

Comment: oh wow, incredible, it works! you're a life savior/genius/divine spirit

Comment: Thanks, but when you've used this script for years, you know that there is only a handful of things that can stop it from working. This is one I've seen many times before! It's just a question of knowing where the bodies are buried.... ;)

Comment: Once I get it up and running, i'll be sure to let you know so you can check it out :)

Comment: everything is running perfectly! check it out.

http://untetheredthoughts.com/quotes.html

Comment: Looks good, but a couple of suggestions. You've got stray <body>, </body>, and </div> tags in there. Run your page through a validator, like http://validator.w3.org/. On a small display, the images are obscuring part of the thumbstrip, so in your highslide.config.js file, add hs.marginBottom=71; You might as well change hs.dimmingOpacity in that file, as well, rather than resetting it in <script> tags on the page itself. Last, try fixedControls=false instead of fixedControls='fit'; (note that there are no quotes around false - it's a boolean, not a string).